# ValueError: array.array size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. + python update error: Too many open files

Tags: python, github, conda

I am trying to perform the workflow described in this git-hub repository: https://github.com/yos-sk/nanoEM; however, at the "choosing best alignment" step

python src/best_align.py --bam1 1.sorted.bam --bam2 2.sorted.bam  --fastq fastq

I got a "ValueError: array.array size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 24 from PyObject"

The whole message is:

```
python src/best_align.py --bam1 alignment1.sorted.bam --bam2 alignment2.sorted.bam --fastq barcode23fastqgz.tar.gz

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/nanoEM/src/best_align.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pysam
  File "path/to/apps/mambaforge-pypy3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/pysam/__init__.py", line 4, in     <module>
    from pysam.libchtslib import *
  File "pysam/libchtslib.pyx", line 1, in init pysam.libchtslib
# cython: language_level=3
ValueError: array.array size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 24 from PyObject
```

I googled the ValueError and found manly recommendations on updating PyPy, Cython etc. so I updated both. When I tried updating python by: conda update python (in base, where I currently work for this repository) I recieved the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/home/vienna/apps/mambaforge-pypy3/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/conda/cli'
```

I googled this one to, found something on changing file limit might help, so tried to increase the ulimit which worked with ulimit -n 2048, resulting in the same error, it did not work anymore with ulimit -n 4096

Now I am not sure to what error I should stick; if I get to increase the limit of files - will that solve my problem, or is that just a symptom of a completely different problem, and actually I don't care which python version it is and if I can update it or not, as long, as I can perform the first task...

Info:
Python 3.9.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (feeb267e, Jan 18 2023, 16:13:01)
[PyPy 7.3.11 with GCC 11.3.0]

I googled as mentioned above and read threads on the arrray.array error as well as on the file limit error, however the suggested solutions did not help so far.

I am new to command lines and would be greatful for any help.

Comment: It helped to install everything into a new conda environment. Did not solve this issue but it works at least.